# Object Required Run-Time Error 424 on wb.close

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a VBA code to 
1. open file;
2. copy sheet and paste onto current workbook;
3. close source workbook.

Everything works fine till point number 3, where I get the Run-time error 4244 object required.

If you look at the code below, I believe the problem lies with "wb.close". I could use some help here!

New excel vba guy here trying to be more efficient

```
Sub ImportOriginated()

Dim fileNameAndPath As Variant
Dim SrcWbk As Workbook

fileNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Origination File To Be Opened")
If fileNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
Workbooks.Open Filename:=fileNameAndPath
Worksheets("LoanBookLocalCurrencyfilteredby").Activate
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Workbooks("Portfolio Reporting 
Dashboard.xlsm").Sheets(Workbooks("Portfolio Reporting 
Dashboard.xlsm").Worksheets.Count)
wb.Close

End Sub
```

The source file which I've copied from should close.

Comment: Did you indent to call `SrcWbk.Close` instead? Although I don't see you initializing it anywhere. You probably want to `Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open ...` first.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `Set` your object before you can use it! If you add `Option Explicit` to the top of your code, VBA will be kind enough to notify you of mistakes like this

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Revision()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim fn As String
Dim Temp As Workbook

fn = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Origination File to be Opened")

If fn <> "" Then

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fn)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("LoanBookLocalCurrencyfilterdby")
    Set Temp = Workbooks("Portfolio Reporting Dashboard.xlsm")

    ws.Copy After:=Temp.Sheets(Temp.Sheets.Count)
    wb.Close

End If
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

- No allocation of `wb`
- No allocation of `SrcWbk`
- Extra `"` in counting worksheets

**Try:**

```
Sub ImportOriginated()

Dim fileNameAndPath As Variant
Dim SrcWbk As Workbook
Dim num As Integer

fileNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Origination File To Be Opened")
If fileNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub

Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open(fileNameAndPath)
num = Workbooks("Portfolio Reporting Dashboard.xlsm").Worksheets.Count
Worksheets("LoanBookLocalCurrencyfilteredby").Copy After:=Workbooks("Portfolio Reporting Dashboard.xlsm").Sheets(num)

SrcWbk.Close False

End Sub
```